# how to retrieve values passed from MicrositeURL for use with SSJS

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs

I am building a custom preference/unsubscribe center in Cloud Pages with SSJS.

I'll be using MicrositeURL('xxxxxx') within the footer of emails to get to the landing page. How can I retrieve the SubscriberKey, JobID, and BatchID from the passed subscriber info to use in my SSJS calls?

Answer (score 1):

You should used the [RequestParameter](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/requestparameter.htm) ampscript function

Eg.

```
%%[
SET @SusbcriberKey = RequestParameter('_subscriberKey')
SET @JobId = RequestParameter('jobID')
SET @BatchId = RequestParameter('batchId')
]%%

%%=v(@SusbcriberKey)=%%
%%=v(@JobId)=%%
%%=v(@BatchId)=%%
```

To do this via SSJS, you would need the [GetAttributeValue](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_platformFieldAttributeGetAttributeValue.htm) function

eg.

```
<script runat=server>
  Platform.Load("Core","1");
  var subscriberKey = Platform.Variable.GetAttributeValue('_subcriberkey');
  Platform.Response.Write(subscriberKey);
</script>
```

Comment: is there a way to do it without using ampscipt?

Comment: You could use SSJS.

Comment: @PauletteVallad updated my answer

Comment: you're missing platform load library in your code @Data_Kid

Comment: no worries @Data_Kid